# Combining the results of two tables in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a query

```
select* from MedicationCombination mc
where mc.MedicationId = 2
```

And the result of the query is:

```
Name        Dosage
-----       ------
Med1        12
Med2        14
Med3        16
```

I want to put this query into a Stored Procedure which will take MedicationId as parameter and return result as:

```
Name                 Dosage
----                 ------
Med1/Med2/Med3      12/14/16
```

I want to use this SP in another query which is:

```
select Id, Category 
from Medication
```

Result is:

```
Id      Category
--      --------
1       Psychotropic
```

I want to use SP in the above query such that the result would be like:

```
Id  Category         Name                Dosage
--  --------         ----                ------
1   Psychotropic    Med1/Med2/Med3      12/14/16
```

What could be the possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the job of your DBMS to format your data the way you'd like them to look, but the application langage's. Therefore, query your database with the first query you posted and use whatever language you're using to format it the way you want.

If you want to make a JOIN with another table, you have to specify conditions. If you'd just like to make a cartesian product, you can use a CROSS JOIN :

```
SELECT Id, Category, Name, Dosage
FROM MedicationCombination
CROSS JOIN Medication
WHERE MedicationId = 2
```

Comment: I want to do something like this:
`SELECT Id, Catgeory, dbo.spGetNameDosage(Id)
WHERE Id=2`

Comment: @asma : Yes, but I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @asma I cannot disagree more with Vicent's Savard statement. There are tons of cases where you actually do these types of transformations. Almost any DBMS worth 5 cents provides means to do this precisely because is a common, needed, task. I just implemented one approach and there are more ways to do it.

Comment: @Icarus : It may be common, it's still not the role of the DBMS. The DBMS should provide the data, it should not attempt to format it. I don't disagree about the usefulness of such formatting, I disagree about the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT @YourMedicationID AS CategoryId
        ( SELECT    ( Name + '/' )
          FROM      MedicationCombination p
          WHERE     p.MedicationId = p2.MedicationId
          ORDER BY  Name
        FOR
          XML PATH('')
        ) AS NAME ,
        ( SELECT    ( CAST(Dosage AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/' )
          FROM      MedicationCombination p
          WHERE     p.MedicationId = p2.MedicationId
          ORDER BY  Name
        FOR
          XML PATH('')
        ) AS Dosage
FROM    MedicationCombination p2
WHERE   p2.MedicationId = @YourMedicationID
GROUP BY NAME ,
        MedicationId
```

Produces this:

```
CategoryId     NAME              Dosage

2              Med1/Med2/Med3/   12/14/16/
```

Joining to your Medication Table should be trivial now.

```
select * from Medication m 
join (result from previous query) t on t.CategoryId=m.CategoryID
```